# No space between label and buttons in Unanswered Questions top layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When accessing the Unanswered Questions list for a specific tag, *sometimes* there is no space between the label and the buttons in the top layout.

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python-3.x?tab=newest

*(no sidebar)*
[image: bug_python_no-sidebar]

*(with sidebar)*
[image: bug_python_with-sidebar]

This is on Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu16 on a 24" 1920x1080 monitor.

It's not consistent though.

It's OK for *different* tags on the *same* monitor.
Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ios?tab=newest

[image: ok_ios_with-sidebar]

It's OK for the *same* tags on a *different* monitor (on an iMac 21.5" 1920x1080).
Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python-3.x?tab=newest

[image: ok_python_on-mac]

---

**UPDATE**:
It can also be replicated by adjusting the browser window size.

Example: 1016x172
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ios?tab=newest (previously OK)

[image: ng_ios_chrome-resized_ubuntu]

Comment: I can get the problem with no spacing using Chrome and setting responsive view 1172 width and basically any height

Comment: I believe the "inconsistency" is only caused by the length of the number of questions. With six figures, "accepted" doesn't fit on the first line, with five figures it does. The iMac seems to use a different font (?) which makes it not fit even with five figures. You might see the same behavior on the iMac when you look at [a tag with a four figure question count](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/tkinter) ?

Comment: @fhdrsdg Hmmm I get your point, I also thought it depends on the number. But I also get [some tags like this](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/batch-file) on my Mac that have 5 figures but "accepted" is still on the first line. Checking it now, I think it's more of a screen-width problem (?), because it can be replicated by adjusting the browser width (ex. sometimes the last word is "upvoted").

Comment: @GinoMempin I think that's it's just a combination of the width of the characters *barely* fitting into the width of the div. Since there's no margin between te div with the text and the buttons, when it barely fits there's no space between the text and the buttons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This bug has been fixed and will be live soon. Thanks for letting us know!